# Set cookie from form (html/php)

Tags: php, cookies

I have a php page with a form which I want to search the user database from for a username match. This is my code:

```
<form id="searchuser" name="searchuser" method="post" action="">
    Enter a username to search for: 
    <label>
        <input type="text" name="uname" id="uname" />
    </label>
    <label>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Search" />
    </label>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
</form>
```

Do I need to put `setcookie()` in the action?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `action` field of a form should contain URL (relative or absolute) of the php script which the browser will navigate into while passing the form fields as a POST request.

For example, you can create a php script named `search.php`, set `action="search.php"` in the form and then access the fields of the form in that script using `$_POST['uname']` for example.

Not sure what you need to set the cookies for in this form but to set a cookie you need to put the setcookie() call somewhere in your php script, NOT in the HTML code. Also you need to call the setcookie() before any HTML output in your php script.

Comment: I would like to have my 'SELECT * FROM userdatabase WHERE username = textboxvalue' I'm just not sure how.

Comment: In that handler script you can use `mysql_query("SELECT * FROM userdatabase WHERE username = \"".str_replace("\"", "\\\"", $_POST["uname"])."\"")`